# how do i force install4j NOT to overwrite specific files when doing an update

Tags: java, install4j

I have created my Install4j project and I am happy with the installation, un-installation and update process so far. However, a new situation have presented itself where I need to stop install4j from overwriting a specific file in the user's installation directory when the user does an update to an new version of the product. Can anyone tell me how to force/configure install4j so that it does not overwrite a specific file when updating an existing installation.

For example, when I install my application I include a database file (mydb.script) as part of the installation files so that the user will have a database ready to use. I found out that when I create a new version of my application and install it again, install4j already detect that I have a previous version install and ask if i want to update that version. I click 'Yes' and it does its job. However, during this process, it actually overwritten the previous database with the one inside the installer (resulting in the user losing all of their data that they have entered since the first installation). I don't want this behavior. I want to tell install4j to not overwrite this particular file if it exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overwrite policy can be controlled in the distribution tree. See the screen shot below, it shows the distribution tree of the "Hello world" sample project. The vmoptions file should not be overwritten, so its overwrite policy is set to "never".

[image]

If you include files with a directory entry and just want to change the overwrite policy for a single file, simply add the single file in addition to the directory entry (you might have to create parent directories manually in that case). The settings for single entries will override settings for directory entries.

Comment: @Ingo How to do it for version 6.1.6?

Comment: @Marckaraujo It's still the same procedure.

Comment: @IngoKegel I have a similar situation where I dont want to overwrite a file during an update but that file is not present in distribution tree . How can I handle this ?

Comment: Then the file will not be overwritten, because it is not present. Please ask another question and explain your problem there.